# Derivative of $\|A - S\,S^\mathsf{T}\|_\mathsf{F}^2$ wrt. $S$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, operator-theory, convex-optimization

Fix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and let $f : M_{nm}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(S) = \tfrac{1}{2}\|A - S\,S^\mathsf{T}\|_\mathsf{F}^2$ (yes I do mean the *transpose* and not the adjoint). I want to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}$. From the Matrix Cookbook 2.8.1 ([link](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf)) we could use the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial S_{ij}} = -\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})\frac{\partial S S^\mathsf{T}}{\partial S_{ij}}\right].$$

Working with this we can see
$$\frac{\partial S S^\mathsf{T}_{kl}}{\partial S_{ij}} = \begin{cases}2 s_{ij} & \text{if } k=l=i\\s_{lj} & \text{if }k=i\neq j\\s_{kj} & \text{if }j=i\neq k\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

so $$\frac{\partial S S^\mathsf{T}}{\partial S_{ij}} = S_je_i^\mathsf{T} + e_iS_j^\mathsf{T}$$ where $S_j$ is the $j$-th column of $S$. It follows that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial S_{ij}} = -\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})(S_je_i^\mathsf{T} + e_iS_j^\mathsf{T})\right].$$

**How can I simplify this further**? Ideally I would have a closed form expression for $f'(S)$ without having to index with coordinates.

Comment: also yes I did tag this as 'convex optimization' even though this isn't a convex function because the problem is very similar to those seen in convex optimization

Comment: if you only need the answer, a nice tool to compute this kind of problem is http://www.matrixcalculus.org/matrixCalculus :)

Comment: @shamisen wow that's an awesome tool thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the derivative of this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125499/what-is-the-derivative-of-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, write
$$
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})(S_je_i^\mathsf{T} + e_iS_j^\mathsf{T})\right] = 
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})S_je_i^\mathsf{T}\right]
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})e_iS_j^\mathsf{T})\right]
$$
Now, note that
$$
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})S_je_i^\mathsf{T}\right] = 
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[e_i^\mathsf{T}(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T}S_j\right]
\\ = 
-e_i^\mathsf{T}(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})S_j
\\ = 
-e_i^\mathsf{T}(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})(S e_j) 
\\ =
-[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})S]_{i,j}
$$
Similarly, 
$$
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})e_iS_j^\mathsf{T}\right] = 
-[S^T(A^T - SS^T)]_{j,i} = 
-[(A - SS^T)S]_{i,j}
$$
All together, we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial S_{i,j}} = 
-\mathsf{tr}\,\left[(A^\mathsf{T} - SS^\mathsf{T})(S_je_i^\mathsf{T} + e_iS_j^\mathsf{T})\right] = -[(A + A^T - 2SS^T)S]_{i,j}
$$
Your matrix form for $f'(S)$ depends which convention you follow, so I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Let me know if any of these steps need clarification; I was pretty terse since I just wanted to get to an answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks for such a quick response! :)

Comment: What @Omnomnomnom has is correct, but since I like matrix derivations better, I added an answer deriving it differently for the whole matrix $S$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the double-contraction product, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and the auxilliary variable $$M=SS^T-A$$
you can write the function, its differential & gradient very succinctly 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \frac{1}{2}\,M:M \cr
df
 &= M:dM = M:(dS\,S^T+S\,dS^T) \cr
 &= MS:dS + S^TM:dS^T \cr
 &= (M+M^T)S:dS \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial S} &= (M+M^T)S = (2SS^T-A^T-A)S \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
      \|A - S\,S^\mathsf{T}\|_\mathsf{F}^2 &= tr((A-SS^T)^T(A-SS^T))  \\
       &= tr(A^TA)-2 tr(A^TSS^T)+tr(SS^TSS^T) 
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \begin{aligned}
      \frac{\partial f(S)}{\partial S}&=\tfrac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial S} tr(A^TA)-2\frac{\partial}{\partial S}tr(A^TSS^T)+\frac{\partial}{\partial S} tr(SS^TSS^T)) \\
       &= \tfrac{1}{2}(0-2\frac{\partial tr(A^TSS^T)}{\partial S}+\frac{\partial tr(SS^TSS^T)}{\partial S})  \\
       &\text{with some abuse of notation:}\\
       &=\tfrac{1}{2}( 2\frac{ tr(\partial(A^TSS^T))}{\partial S}+\frac{tr(\partial(SS^TSS^T))}{\partial S})  \\
       &\text{by circularity of trace norm:}\\
       &= \tfrac{1}{2}(2\frac{ tr(S^TA^T\partial S)+tr(A^TS\partial S^T)}{\partial S}+\frac{tr(S^TSS^T\partial S)+tr(SS^TS\partial S^T)+tr(S^TSS^T\partial S)+tr(SS^TS\partial S^T)}{\partial S} ) \\
       &= \tfrac{1}{2}(2 AS+ 2 A^TS+SS^TS+SS^TS+SS^TS+SS^TS) \\
       &=\tfrac{1}{2}( 2 (A+A^T)S+ 4 SS^TS) \\
       &=  (A+A^T)S+ 2 SS^TS \\
       &=  (A+A^T+ 2 SS^T)S \\
     \end{aligned}
\end{equation}